# Import OVA once, deploy multiple

Tags: vmware-vcenter, ovf

Is there a way using the `ovftool` to import an OVA image once and create multiple VMs from it?

Answer (score 1):

No.

{mandatory extra characters due to minimum answer limit}

Comment: I had seen something about converting the OVA to a VM template?

Comment: Yep you can 100% do that but that's not your question.